# Check correct date

Tags: android, kotlin

good afternoon! All good?
I'm making an application, where it is possible to schedule queries, however, I would like it to be possible for queries with past dates and times to be hidden.
Can someone help me on how to do a check with DateFormat, or another solution?

In the image, we have two queries, one within the "validity", and one "expired". The idea is that the one with the past date was hidden from the view. This function was made with ArrayList.

```
data class MyAdapter(private val userList : ArrayList<User>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user : User = userList[position]
        holder.tvName.text = user.cliente
        holder.tvFuncionario.text = user.funcionario
        holder.tvData.text = user.data
        holder.tvHora.text = user.hora
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val tvName : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        val tvFuncionario : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFuncionario)
        val tvData : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvData)
        val tvHora : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHora)
    }
```

```
fun EventChangeListener() {

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().time
        val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar)

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("agendamento")
            .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
                override fun onEvent(

                    value: QuerySnapshot?,
                    error: FirebaseFirestoreException?

                ) {

                    if (error != null) {
                        Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
                        return
                    }

                    for (dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                        if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User::class.java))

                        }
                    }
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the functionality of hiding queries with past dates and times, you can modify your EventChangeListener function to filter out the expired queries before adding them to the userArrayList. You can compare the query's date and time with the current date and time to determine if it has expired.

Here's how you can do that:

```
fun EventChangeListener() {

val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().time

db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
db.collection("agendamento")
    .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
        override fun onEvent(
            value: QuerySnapshot?,
            error: FirebaseFirestoreException?
        ) {
            if (error != null) {
                Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
                return
            }

            val filteredList = ArrayList<User>()

            for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    val user = dc.document.toObject(User::class.java)

                    // Parse user's date and time
                    val userDateTime = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
                        .parse("${user.data} ${user.hora}")

                    // Compare with current date and time
                    if (userDateTime != null && userDateTime >= currentDate) {
                        filteredList.add(user)
                    }
                }
            }

            userArrayList.clear()
            userArrayList.addAll(filteredList)
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    })
}
```

In this code, we're parsing the date and time from the User object using SimpleDateFormat, then comparing it with the current date and time. If the user's date and time are greater than or equal to the current date and time, we add it to the filteredList. After iterating through all the document changes, we clear the existing userArrayList and add the filtered items back. This ensures that only future events are displayed in your RecyclerView.